# Use theme in a custom folder in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to use a theme in a specific folder and display the header of the theme

```
   define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

    /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require( '../../wp-blog-header.php' );
    get_header();
```

I have these error :

open_basedir restriction in effect. File(F:\xampp\htdocs\fredon\wp-blog-header.php) is not within the allowed path(s)

Answer (score 0):

Try to load wp-load file like: require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

Comment: I tried but wordpress search for wp-blog-header.php in the theme directory's specific folder and not in the root directory of wordpress, so i have to copy the theme to the specific directory ?

Comment: wp-blog-header.php file is the root directory file and if you need to include it in theme directory file you need to use this like  require_once( dirname( dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ )))) . '/wp-load.php' );

Comment: I think the real problem is open_basedir restriction is not within the allowed path(s)

Comment: You can check .htaccess file too